# How to include submodules located in root using setup.py?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-packaging

I created a simple Python package with the following structure:

```
foo/
├─ bar/
│  ├─ __init__.py
├─ __init__.py
baz/
├─ __init__.py
setup.py
```

I want the `baz` package to be available on the namespace as `foo.baz`.

Here is the *setup.py* I am using:

```py
from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='Foo',
      version='1.0',
      description='Test Package',
      namespace_packages = [
          'foo',
      ],
      packages = [
          'foo.bar',
          'foo.baz',
      ],
      package_dir = {
          "foo.baz": "baz",
      },
      include_package_data = True,
     )
```

However, installing this package (using `pip install -e .`) results in the `foo.baz` package being unavailable:

```
>>> import foo.bar
>>> import foo.baz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo.baz'
```

How can I modify the *setup.py* to be able to import `foo.baz`?

**Edit:** it works if the package is not installed in editable mode (i.e. setuptools "develop mode"). Is this a quirk with pip?

Comment: you need to move `baz` folder into subfolder under the root. Both `foo` and `baz` are pointing to your current root directory (`foo.baz`??..both are at the same level i.e., root).

Comment: See my updated question. It works when the package is not installed in editable mode.